# How to : modifiy pinax Group types

Tags: python, django, pinax

In Pinax documentation :

> Group support in Pinax allows you to define any type of group. Pinax comes bundled with two types of groups:

```
    tribes — used in social_project
    projects — used in code_project
A group app can have any content object associated with it. Pinax includes several apps that are group aware:

    tasks
    photos
    wiki
    topics
```

In projects type there are 2 content apps wiki and tpics

How can I add more content apps ( photo , video and maps ) beside topics and wiki ?

Answer (score 0):

Pinax also comes with photos, they use photologue  (part of the social_project setup)

I'm really not sure what you are asking.

python manage startapp maps will allow you to create your own apps.  Are you looking for prebuilt apps?  You might look here for more Django packages http://djangopackages.com/

Comment: tajnk you for replying , I know Pinax include photos and maps apps but how to add these apps to project group type ? 
In code project pinax have code group type include tasks, topics and wiki how to add the photo and location apps to them

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what you are asking.